# Targeting a single image in CSS

Tags: html, css

With the following css/htms

```
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="#bottom"><img title="power gains" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/powergains.png"}}" alt="show power gains"></a></p>

<p><a title="Navistar" href="http://bluesparkautomotive.com/instructionfiles/073_ppb.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/installation.png"}}" alt="" /></a></p>
```

I need to target the bottom image with the following:

```
img:hover{box-shadow: 6px 6px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.6); transform:scale(1.02);}
img:focus{box-shadow: 12px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7); width: 46%; transform: none;}
```

And leave all other images without the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `p > a[title="Navistar"] > img`.
The `a[title="Navistar"]` is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a specific image to be chosen, you can add an `id` tag to the `img` element so that it can be specifically selected. `id` tags are unique and cannot be shared, but the `id` name can be chosen by yourself.

```
<img src="" id="id123" />
```

And in your CSS, use a `#` to specify that you are looking for an id:

```
#id123:hover {[css]}
```

This is not really related to your question but it would be good for future use. You can use a `class` tag if you want to choose a group of elements to be styled the same way. This can be done by:

```
<img src="" class="class123" />
```

`class` is not specific to 1 element but can be shared among a group of elements that require the same style. You can locate such elements with `.` in your CSS:

```
.class123:hover {[css]}
```